# Matching algorithm score based on fields

Tags: oracle, algorithm, matching

I'm working on a matching program that matches 2 data-sets using a combination of the fields, like first name, last name, tax ID, SSN, DOB, Address... The data-sets are always different and the fields that I have available for matching will differ. I have an app in MS Access where i'm mapping the field names available to my list of fields.

I've ranked each field on strength from 0 to 100 (this is all subjective, of course, since I have no way to know how unique a field is. For example, I have DOB at 50% but is DOB really 50% unique? How unique is a last name? So, ranking correctly is my first problem since the order of the matches will depend on this rank).

Below is my table that has all the fields, the strength I assigned to them (from 0 to 100) and the sort order (it's tied to the strength, basically, sorting in the order of strongest to weakest).

[image]

After mapping, I run code that creates permutations of the SortIDPracs field.So, I end up with all possible field combinations for this data-set.
Below is a sample of the matching categories. As you can see, i'm running each category 4 times:

1.with first name and last name

2.with first initial last name

3 with first name, first 4 letters of last name

4.without a name

[image]

Below is the code that creates the listing above. You can plug in different SortIdPracs values and you will, obviously, get a different listing of combinations.

```
    DECLARE
       VarCountOfFields NUMBER;
       VarCurrentFieldNo NUMBER;
       VarFirstNo NUMBER;
       VarCountOfRanked VARCHAR2(1000);
       VarSQLSelect1 VARCHAR2(1000);
       VarSQLSelect2 VARCHAR2(4000);
       VarSQLSelect2MatchedText VARCHAR2(4000);
       VarSQLSelect2SQL1 VARCHAR2(4000);
       VarSQLSelect2SQL2 VARCHAR2(4000);
       VarSQLSelect2MatchWorth VARCHAR2(4000);
       VarSQLFrom2 VARCHAR2(1000);
       VarSQLJoins2 VARCHAR2(1000);
       VarSQLText CLOB;
BEGIN
       TruncateTable_P('MATCH_300');

       INSERT INTO MATCH_300
              SELECT     LEVEL  Lvl
                        ,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(col1, ', ') PathNo
                    FROM (SELECT SortIDPracs Col1
                                ,SortIDPracs Col2
                            FROM (SELECT 101 SortIDPracs FROM DUAL
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT 102 SortIDPracs FROM DUAL
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT 104 SortIDPracs FROM DUAL
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT 105 SortIDPracs FROM DUAL
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT 106 SortIDPracs FROM DUAL
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT 107 SortIDPracs FROM DUAL)) tmp
              CONNECT BY PRIOR col1 < col2
                ORDER BY LEVEL
                        ,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(col1, ', ');

       --can't combine, string concatenation too long error
       TruncateTable_P('MATCH_301');

       INSERT INTO MATCH_301
              SELECT ROWNUM UniqueID
                    ,SUBSTR(PathNo, 3, 99) Permutations
                    ,(TRIM(LENGTH(SUBSTR(PathNo, 3, 99))) - TRIM(LENGTH(TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(PathNo, 3, 99), 'A,', 'A')))) + 1 CountOfFields
                FROM (SELECT   DISTINCT tmp.*
                          FROM MATCH_300 tmp
                      ORDER BY 1 DESC
                              ,2);


       SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT mf.SortIDPracs)
         INTO VarCountOfFields
         FROM MATCH_MAPPING tmp
             ,MATCH_FIELDS mf
        WHERE     1 = 1
              AND mf.SortIDPracs IS NOT NULL
              AND tmp.MatchFieldID = mf.MatchFieldID
              AND tmp.ProjectCriteriaID = 6;

       VarCurrentFieldNo := 1;

       WHILE VarCurrentFieldNo <= VarCountOfFields LOOP
              IF VarCurrentFieldNo <= 2 THEN
                     VarFirstNo := 1;
              ELSE
                     VarFirstNo := 2;
              END IF;

              IF VarSQLSelect1 IS NULL THEN
                     VarSQLSelect1 := ',REGEXP_SUBSTR(tmp.Permutations, ''[^ ]+'', ' || VarFirstNo || ', ' || VarCurrentFieldNo || ') Permutations' || VarCurrentFieldNo;
                     VarSQLSelect2 :=
                               ',mt'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || '.FieldName FieldName'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || ',mt'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || '.FieldStrengthPracs FieldStrengthPracs'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || ',mt'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || '.StrengthRankPracs StrengthRankPracs'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo;
                     VarSQLFrom2 := ',MATCH_FIELDS mt' || VarCurrentFieldNo;
                     VarSQLJoins2 := 'AND tmp.Permutations' || VarCurrentFieldNo || ' = mt' || VarCurrentFieldNo || '.SortIDPracs(+)';
                     VarSQLSelect2MatchedText := 'FieldName' || VarCurrentFieldNo;
                     VarSQLSelect2SQL1 := 'FieldName' || VarCurrentFieldNo;
                     VarSQLSelect2SQL2 := 'mt.'' || FieldName' || VarCurrentFieldNo || ' || '' = pr.''  || FieldName' || VarCurrentFieldNo;
                     VarSQLSelect2MatchWorth := '+ NVL(FieldStrengthPracs' || VarCurrentFieldNo || ',0) ';
                     VarCountOfRanked := '+ NVL(StrengthRankPracs' || VarCurrentFieldNo || ',0) ';
              ELSE
                     VarSQLSelect1 :=
                               VarSQLSelect1
                            || ',REGEXP_SUBSTR(tmp.Permutations, ''[^ ]+'', '
                            || VarFirstNo
                            || ', '
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || ') Permutations'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo;
                     VarSQLSelect2 :=
                               VarSQLSelect2
                            || ',mt'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || '.FieldName FieldName'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || ',mt'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || '.FieldStrengthPracs FieldStrengthPracs'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || ',mt'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || '.StrengthRankPracs StrengthRankPracs'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo;
                     VarSQLFrom2 := VarSQLFrom2 || ',MATCH_FIELDS mt' || VarCurrentFieldNo;
                     VarSQLJoins2 := VarSQLJoins2 || 'AND tmp.Permutations' || VarCurrentFieldNo || ' = mt' || VarCurrentFieldNo || '.SortIDPracs(+)';
                     VarSQLSelect2MatchedText :=
                               VarSQLSelect2MatchedText
                            || ' || CASE WHEN FieldName'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || ' IS NOT NULL THEN '', '' || FieldName'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || ' END';
                     VarSQLSelect2SQL1 :=
                            VarSQLSelect2SQL1 || ' || CASE WHEN FieldName' || VarCurrentFieldNo || ' IS NOT NULL THEN '', '' || FieldName' || VarCurrentFieldNo || ' END';
                     VarSQLSelect2SQL2 :=
                               VarSQLSelect2SQL2
                            || '  || CASE WHEN FieldName'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || ' IS NOT NULL THEN '' AND mt.'' || FieldName'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || ' || '' = pr.'' || FieldName'
                            || VarCurrentFieldNo
                            || ' END ';
                     VarSQLSelect2MatchWorth := VarSQLSelect2MatchWorth || '+ NVL(FieldStrengthPracs' || VarCurrentFieldNo || ',0) ';
                     VarCountOfRanked := VarCountOfRanked || '+ NVL(StrengthRankPracs' || VarCurrentFieldNo || ',0) ';
              END IF;

              VarCurrentFieldNo := VarCurrentFieldNo + 1;
              COMMIT;
       END LOOP;

       DropObject_P('TABLE', 'MATCH_302');

       VarSQLText := 'CREATE TABLE MATCH_302
AS
       SELECT   UniqueID, CountOfFields ' || VarSQLSelect1 || '
           FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UniqueID
                                ,CountOfFields
                                ,REPLACE(Permutations, '', '', '' '') Permutations
                   FROM MATCH_301) tmp
       ORDER BY 1';

       --   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(VarSQLText);
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VarSQLText;

       COMMIT;

       DropObject_P('TABLE', 'MATCH_303');

       VarSQLText := 'CREATE TABLE MATCH_303
AS
       SELECT   UniqueID, CountOfFields ' || VarSQLSelect2 || '
           FROM MATCH_302 tmp ' || VarSQLFrom2 || '
           WHERE 1=1  ' || VarSQLJoins2 || '
       ORDER BY 1';

       --  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(VarSQLText);
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VarSQLText;

       COMMIT;

       DropObject_P('TABLE', 'MATCH_304');

       VarSQLText :=
                 'CREATE TABLE MATCH_304
AS
       SELECT   UniqueID, CountOfFields+2 CountOfFields 
             ,1      PassNo, ''First Name, Last Name, ''  || '
              || VarSQLSelect2MatchedText
              || ' MatchedText, ''FN, LN, ''  || '
              || VarSQLSelect2SQL1
              || ' SQL1, ''mt.FN = pr.FN AND mt.LN = pr.LN AND '
              || VarSQLSelect2SQL2
              || ' SQL2, (30'
              || VarSQLSelect2MatchWorth
              || ') MatchWorth, (0'
              || VarCountOfRanked
              || ') CountOfRanked
           FROM MATCH_303 tmp
       UNION ALL    SELECT   UniqueID, CountOfFields+2 
             ,2      PassNo, ''First Initial, Last Name, ''  ||  '
              || VarSQLSelect2MatchedText
              || ' MatchedText, ''FN1, LN, ''   || '
              || VarSQLSelect2SQL1
              || ' SQL1, ''mt.FN1 = pr.FN1 AND mt.LN = pr.LN AND '
              || VarSQLSelect2SQL2
              || ' SQL2, (25'
              || VarSQLSelect2MatchWorth
              || ') MatchWorth, (0'
              || VarCountOfRanked
              || ') CountOfRanked
           FROM MATCH_303 tmp
       UNION ALL    SELECT   UniqueID, CountOfFields+2 
             ,3      PassNo, ''First Name, First 4 Letters Of Last Name, ''   || '
              || VarSQLSelect2MatchedText
              || ' MatchedText, ''FN, LN4, ''   || '
              || VarSQLSelect2SQL1
              || ' SQL1, ''mt.FN = pr.FN AND mt.LN4 = pr.LN4 AND '
              || VarSQLSelect2SQL2
              || ' SQL2, (10'
              || VarSQLSelect2MatchWorth
              || ') MatchWorth, (0'
              || VarCountOfRanked
              || ') CountOfRanked
           FROM MATCH_303 tmp
       UNION ALL    SELECT   UniqueID, CountOfFields 
             ,4      PassNo,  '
              || VarSQLSelect2MatchedText
              || ' MatchedText, '
              || VarSQLSelect2SQL1
              || ' SQL1, '''
              || VarSQLSelect2SQL2
              || ' SQL2, (0'
              || VarSQLSelect2MatchWorth
              || ') MatchWorth, (0'
              || VarCountOfRanked
              || ') CountOfRanked
           FROM MATCH_303 tmp ';

       -- DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(VarSQLText);
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VarSQLText;

       COMMIT;
END;
```

This query will give you the data from the screenshot above

```
    SELECT   DISTINCT tmp.*
    FROM MATCH_304 tmp
ORDER BY 1,3;
```

I then go down and loop through each matching category using the joins from the SQL2 field. SQL1 field is the list of fields. So i have a procedure that loops through each category and plugs in the values from those 2 fields into a query

A sample query for one of the categories looks like this (so, this is a loop for a FN, LN, SSN, Address match).

```
  INSERT INTO MATCH_MATCHED
          SELECT --+append ordered use_hash(mt,pr)
                 DISTINCT mt.UniqueID
                         ,pr.UniqueID
                         ,3040
                         ,2
            FROM MATCH_MATCH mt
                ,(SELECT DISTINCT UniqueID
                                 ,FN
                                 ,LN
                                 ,SSN
                                 ,Address
                    FROM MATCH_PROVS pr) pr
           WHERE     1 = 1
                 AND mt.FN = pr.FN
                 AND mt.LN = pr.LN
                 AND mt.Address = pr.Address
                 AND mt.SSN = pr.SSN;
```

I have several problems

1. Need help assigning strength of each field (I'm pretty sure mind are inadequate). If i know that there's a total of 100 TINs (for example) and i know that in the worst case scenario, 20 providers will share a TIN, how do i calculate a % that matching on TIN alone is a correct match, is it 80% in this example?
2. Need to find a way to assign a strengths % score to each matching category. I thought of summing up the scores of all fields and dividing by the number of fields but the results aren't true everywhere. For example, SSN will score higher than FN, LN, SSN, DOB, City.
3. I need to find a way for that score to vary with each data-set. For example, if I'm given a dataset that has FN, LN, SSN, DOB, address, City, state, zip, i won't be too happy with a match on FN, LN, Address, since it should've also matched on SSN and/or DOB. So the score for this match shouldn't be too high since there were so many more fields it could've matched on. But if I'm given a set that has FN, LN, address, then a match on FN, LN, Address becomes a 100% match. So this score has to take into consideration the fields available at the start of the match
4. The score has to be precise enough that I can trust it to dynamically exclude some categories at the time of the run. For example, I never want to trust City, State match alone. So ideally, I want to look at the score at the time of the run and not even run this line because the score for it would be under some threshold

I cannot come up with a scoring system that will let me accomplish all this.

Comment: Can you please include a small example? Maybe two datasets with only 4 entries each, and explain how you would match them?

Comment: Sure!! Will do in a little while

Comment: @Stef hey, i updated the original. hopefully this gives you enough info, if not, let me know. thank you for even showing interest!